# Is there a way to set the brushing extents through code using d3.parcoords.js?

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

At runtime new data is added to parallel coordinate graph and according to that I need to adjust Brush extent Height programmatically.

[graph before adding data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQigH.png)

Here I need to adjus BrushExtent , currently it looks like this

[graph after adding new data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkHmL.png)